# Почему ноутбук не загружается?

Tags: windows, bios

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего ничего не загружает
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. жесткий диск активно работает?
   может обновления грузит/устанавливает и вообще надо часов 10 подождать
2. пробовали из под SafeMode загрузиться, а потом перезагрузиться нормально?
3. если есть мышка и больше ничего нет - значит возможно не загрузился Проводник (который за рабочий стол отвечает)

попробуйте вызвать диспетчер задач (через Ctrl-Alt-Del) и из под него запустить новую задачу (в меню) и ввести 'explorer.exe'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если поставили "задача решена" знак, то скажите PLZ что именно из этого было у вас?